# Ubuntu 16.04 slow performance after NVidia drivers installation

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, xorg, msi, nvidia-geforce

I recently installed Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS in my MSI GE70 2PE Apache Pro. Everything has been Ok until I've installed NVidia Drivers.

When I select NVidia card in Prime and re-login, everything works laggy, even scrolling down in Firefox. I've tested some driver versions (340, 367, 375, 378) and the same thing happens with every of them. I've used both proprietary drivers and `ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa` drivers, with identical results. Secure boot is disabled.

Don't know what more can I do. Any help would be appreciated.

**Edit**
The output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` is what follows:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
DeviceName:  Onboard IGD
Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
Kernel driver in use: i915
--
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107M [GeForce GTX 860M] (rev ff)
Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_367, nvidia_367_drm
03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5249 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] RTS5249 PCI Express Card Reader
```

**Edit 2**

Same command's output with nvidia card selected in prime:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
DeviceName:  Onboard IGD
Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
Kernel driver in use: i915
--
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107M [GeForce GTX 860M] (rev a2)
Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] GM107M [GeForce GTX 860M]
Kernel driver in use: nvidia
Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_378_drm, nvidia_378
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.

Comment: Is Intel selected in PRIME?

Comment: At the moment of the capture it was

Comment: I've added the same output but with Nvidia selected in PRIME under Edit 2